# struct constructor will take space within the struct space?

Tags: c++, sockets, struct

Most of the time I use `struct` to hold all parameters for my socket communication data structure and then I can easily copy, pass or put the entire structure on the socket by just passing the start address and its size.

If I add a constructor to the `struct` for a variable short array, will the constructor occupy any space within the struct? Or can I treat the `struct` with a constructor the same as a `struct` without a constructor, and copy the entire `struct` on to the socket with its start address and its size, and its space is still continuously allocated?

Comment: Note that copying an entire struct across the network this way is fragile and will break if the programs communicating with each other do not have the exact same padding, endian-ness, and value-sizes.  (something to watch out for if you want to communicate across architectures, or even within the same architecture but between instances of your program that were compiled with different compiler settings or different compiler versions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, non-virtual member functions do not contribute to the `sizeof` of your object. The existence of at least one virtual function contribute (however constructors cannot be virtual) since the compiler is usually implementing them via a pointer (vpointer) to an array of pointer to functions (vtable), so it must store that pointer (4 or 8 bytes usually).

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that *having* one or more virtual functions contributes. The function itself doesn't.

Comment: And in case of multiple inheritance you can have even more.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck yes of course, I was considering the simplest case where there's no inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

This question is related with C++ object model. Normal function does not increase data size. However, if we add virtual functions, the compiler will generate __vptr to point to virtual function table which will increase the data size of struct.

For example, I have a.C

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct X
{
    X(){}
    int i;
    int j;

};

int main()
{
    X x;
    cout << sizeof(x) << endl;
}
```

Here, I use my IBM XL C++ Compiler in my machine to compile and run it:

```
xlC -+ a.C
./a.out
```

The output will be 8, which is the same as the struct only has int i and int j.

But if I add two virtual functions:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct X
{
    X(){}
    int i;
    int j;
    virtual void foo(){}
    virtual void bar(){}
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    cout << sizeof(x) << endl;
}
```

If recompile and run it:

```
xlC -+ a.c
./a.out
```

The output will be 16. 8 for two int, 8 for __vptr (my machine is 64 bits).